# What can be done to tackle TCPDF ERROR: [Image] Unable to get image: /img/tmp/product_mini_316_0.jpg?

Tags: php, prestashop, tcpdf

I am using PrestaShop 1.6 for my e-commerce portal. I am getting 'TCPDF ERROR: [Image] Unable to get image: /img/tmp/product_mini_316_0.jpg' error on the validation page for Cash on Delivery.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you can turn off the product pictures on the invoice (Preferences > Orders page) to avoid this error. It seems to be a known issue.